# vmstat is not writing its output to the file

Tags: bash, unix, solaris

I am trying to run vmstat via a bash script every 20 seconds and output the results to a file for several hours. My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
vmstat 20 1000 | ./timestamp.pl >> vmstat.txt
```

timestamp.pl script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>){
print localtime() . "$_ ";}
```

I am calling timestamp.pl to insert timestamp in each line of vmstat output. The script is running on SunOS for about an hour and I dont see any entry in vmstat.txt file. Any ideas why is this or any way to improve it so that it writes the output to the vmstat.txt file?

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem. Works fine with Solaris 11.

Comment: see if you system has `unbuffer`, if so pre-pend that to your `vmstat` line. Or see if you can use a `stdbuf` to read/write in/output like `stdbuf -o0 program | stdbuf -i0 script` . Good luck.

Comment: @Cyrus, the system is solaris 10.

Comment: @shelter, not clear. Can you eloborate?

Comment: @user1471980 The problem is that the `vmstat` output is buffered, and it only writes to the pipe when the buffer fills up. Using the `unbuffer` command will make it think its output is to a terminal, so it won't be buffered.

Comment: Although on Linux it doesn't appear to buffer its output. I'm surprised it's different on Solaris.

Comment: @Barmar, there is no unbuffere command

Comment: If you install `Expect`, I think it will include this command.

Comment: `vmstat 20 1000` will emit a line of output every 20 seconds.  Are you sure it isn't the Perl script that's buffering the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either wait for enough time for the perl output to be flushed (the script will end after about 5h30min) or disable buffering in your perl script by adding this line before the loop:

```
$|++;
```